# AngularJS and reusable UI plugins

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and have been evaluating it. I understand how it can be used to either replace jQuery or used together with it. What I like about jQuery is the plugin architecture as well as the ability to create reusable UI components. There are also a ton of jQuery UI components on the Internet. What I am not seeing is how AngularJS provides a similiar or comparable architecture that allows me to create reusable UI components. Can someone explain how AngularJS does the equivalent of jQuery UI components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same thing using angular custom directives. Just like we have so many JQuery plugins, if you search for angular directives you will find some useful directives (http://angular-ui.github.io/ ).

Here is [the documentation,](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: I googled "angularjs ui widgets" but there isn't any site listing a lot of popular widgets. Do you know of a site listing reusable UI components?